# Move and scale on UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

I am trying to allow the user to edit an existing photo using the move and scale view and allow them to edit any picture they pick or take but I can't get the move and scale view to appear correctly. How do I get the title and circle view to show? This is what it looks like now:
[image]
and this is what I want:[image]

```
  func addImage(sender: UIButton) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

            var numberAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:  { action in
                self.takePhoto()
            })
            alert.addAction(numberAlert)

         numberAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Photo", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:  { action in
            self.choosePhoto()
        })
        alert.addAction(numberAlert)

         numberAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit Photo", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:  { action in
            self.editPhoto()
        })
        alert.addAction(numberAlert)

         numberAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Photo", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:  { action in
            self.deletePhoto()
        })
        alert.addAction(numberAlert)


        let cancelAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)
        cancelAlert.setValue(UIColor.blue, forKey: "titleTextColor")
        alert.addAction(cancelAlert)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func choosePhoto() {
        imagePicker = nil
        imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func takePhoto() {
        imagePicker = nil
        imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.resignFirstResponder()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func editPhoto() {

    }

    func deletePhoto() {

    }

    //MARK: - Saving Image here
    @IBAction func save(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.contact.image!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    }

    //MARK: - Add image to Library
    func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            NSLog("Error saving image: \(error)")
        } else {
           self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.contact.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more information please? Are you receiving an error? If so, what's the description? If not an error, what is the exact behavior you are experiencing?

Comment: I have updated my question. What I am missing is the circle scale field and title.

Comment: I don't use `UIImagePickerController.allowsEditing` in my apps, but some quick testing with the simulator shows some really odd undocumented behavior. Using an iPad (iOS 9.0+) you get the "Move and Scale" in the bottom bar, but any iPhone (iOS 9.0, iOS 10.3, iPhone 4s through iPhone 7plus) do not seem to show this option anywhere.

Comment: i found the answer to my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794187/uiimagepickercontroller-editing-view-circle-overlay